# Server side code in Razor view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to create functions like these in the Razor view engine?

```
@{
    View.Title = "Clients";

    private string GetRowClassName(RowStatus status)
    {
        if (status == Model.SelectedStatus)
            return "selected";
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@functions {
   private string GetRowClassName(RowStatus status) {
     if (status == Model.SelectedStatus)
       return "selected";
    return string.Empty;
  }
}
```

You could also look into the `@helper` syntax but in this case `@functions` is probably better.